# How to save the value of i in a for loop without letting the iteration affecting it

Tags: python, list, for-loop

In this chunk of the code:

```
def lin_search(A,N,X):
  first_occurance = 0
  counter = 0

  for i in range(0, N):
    if counter != X:
      if A[i] == 0:
        first_occurance = i
        counter += 1
        print('True at ' + str(first_occurance) + ' ' + str(counter))
      else:
        continue
    elif counter == X:
      print('Memory has enough space for ' + str(X) + ' amount starting at index ' + str(first_occurance))
      break;
```

The moment `first occurrence` gets assigned to `i`, I want it to stay at that exact value even if the for loop continues. Let's say that `A[2] == 0` and `first_occurance` became `2`.  I want `first_occurance` to remain 2 no matter how long the for loop is running.

If I run

```
memory = [1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0]

lin_search(memory, len(memory), 4)
```

`first_occurance` should be `11` because that is the index where there are 4 consecutive 0s

Comment: `if A[i] == 0 and first_occurance == 0:`?

Comment: @Selcuk Can you elaborate?

Comment: You can change your `if` condition to what I wrote above but @Epsi95's answer is a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize first_occurance to None. It will only get assigned value once
when the condition

```
if(first_occurance == None):
```

will be satisfied. Once first_occurance will be assigned to any value, the above condition doesn't hold true. By this first_occurance will be initialized only once.

Here

```
str(first_occurance if first_occurance else 0)
```

The extra if-else condition is provided so that str is not applied to None. Then it will give 'None'. if first_occurance is None then just give 0.

```py
def lin_search(A,N,X):
  first_occurance = None
  counter = 0

  for i in range(0, N):
    if counter != X:
      if A[i] == 0:
        if(first_occurance == None):
           first_occurance = i
        counter += 1
        print('True at ' + str(first_occurance if first_occurance else 0) + ' ' + str(counter))
      else:
        continue
    elif counter == X:
      print('Memory has enough space for ' + str(X) + ' amount starting at index ' + str(first_occurance if first_occurance else 0))
      break;
```

Not in scope of this question though
Solution for your problem

```py
def lin_search(memory):
    stack = []
    for index, i in enumerate(memory):
        if(i == 0):
            stack.append(i)
            if(len(stack) == 4):
                return index - 3
        else:
            stack.clear()
    return -1 #not found
```

modification to your solution

```py
def lin_search(A,N,X):
    first_occurance = None
    counter = 0

    for i in range(0, N):
        if counter != X:
            if A[i] == 0:
                if(first_occurance == None):
                    first_occurance = i
                counter += 1
                print('True at ' + str(first_occurance) + ' ' + str(counter))
            else:
                first_occurance = None
                counter = 0
        if counter == X:
            print('Memory has enough space for ' + str(X) + ' amount starting at index ' + str(first_occurance))
            break
```

Comment: Do you mind elaborating on your changes instead of just posting an answer?

Comment: The issue with `None` is that it is a built-in Python function. How do I represent it in pseudocode?

Comment: Since your range is (o, N) it is guaranteed that i will be positive. So you can initialize first_occurance to a negative number (ex: first_occurance = -1)and do the same logic.

Comment: Doesn't work. I have a list like `list = [1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0]`. If X equals 4, it should return 11 because indices from index 11 onwards have 4 or more 0s.

Comment: See, you asked how to create a variable that will not change once initialized. The solution is provided for that. I haven't looked at how your code works. If you require please provide input A,N,X and required output and what you want to achieve.

Comment: Okay, I will check, your code needs to be changed for else condition. You can easily implement the search mechanism using stack. I would recommend you look for stack data structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you set `first_occurance` to `None` to begin with, you can check if the variable has ever been set before. Note that I explicitly *do not* check if `first_occurance` is `0`, because `0` can be a valid value - i.e., `first_occurance` could be at the very first index. In this case, it doesn't matter, but it might if you were doing more work inside the `if` block. If you are sure you don't want to do anything other than assignment of `first_occurance` inside the `if` condition, you could make only a single change to your code: `if A[i] == 0 and first_occurance == 0:`

```
def lin_search(A,N,X):
  first_occurance = None # set it to None to begin with
  counter = 0

  for i in range(0, N):
    if counter != X:
      if A[i] == 0 and first_occurance is None: # ensure that first_occurance is only set once
        first_occurance = i
        counter += 1
        print('True at ' + str(first_occurance) + ' ' + str(counter))
      else:
        continue
    elif counter == X:
      print('Memory has enough space for ' + str(X) + ' amount starting at index ' + str(first_occurance or 0))
      break;

    # if you want to use first_occurance down the line and it needs to be set to 0, do it here
    if not first_occurance:
        first_occurance = 0
```